# USB stick doesn't work anymore on Android 11

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s

USB stick doesn't work anymore on Samsung Galaxy S10+ with Android 11 since about Jan 1, 2022. The USB stick is not recognized, not mounted. Mount is refused if I try to do.

The only way to contact the USB stick is via Paragon Software for USB. But this had changed the behavior. A file manager which uses Paragon Software is now unusable slow, it takes hours to display a directory listing. Without any action by myself, a message appeared, saying that I have to restart my phone because a USB stick was removed in a no-proper way. I have followed and restarted my phone.

From that time, the USB stick cannot be used anymore. Because some weeks ago I have lost all contents of the plugged-in SD card (unknown reason and due to features of my provider), and I was not able to restore data until yet, the only storage of my thousands of emails and accompanying files is my USB stick.

Thus please take measures that will help. Please store this text and make it available for me that I can reuse it.

Comment: Try a different SUB stick if it works at all (to detect if the phone or the stick is the problem). Also try to use the USB stick on a PC or a different device where you know it works. Keep in mind that for USB sticks mostly the cheapest and most unreliable flash memory available on the market is used. USB sticks are therefore not good for backups.